# Sum the series $3+6+15+42+123….$ to $n$ terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

This question is from my mathematics exam for 11th graders. This was the last problem on the test and it has stumped me. The question is as follows:

Sum the series $3+6+15+42+123…$ to $n$ terms.

I tried to solve it but it got me nowhere.

At first I set:

$$S=3+6+15+42+123…$$

$$\frac{S}{3}=1+2+5+14+41...$$

$$\frac{S}{3}=3+(6-1)+(15-1)+(42-1)...$$

$$\frac{S}{3}=3+6+15+42...-1(n-2)$$

$$\frac{S}{3}=S-(n-2)$$

$$(n-2)=\frac{2S}{3}$$

$$S=\frac{3(n-2)}{2}$$

But this sum is clearly wrong. I also attempted this:

$S=3+(3+3^1)+(3+3^1+3^2)+(3+3^1+3^2+3^3)+(3+3^1+3^2+3^3+3^4)...$

But this also doesn’t seem to lead me anywhere. I’d appreciate any help with this question.

I should also mention that this exam is for Engineering stream students, who are required to take “advanced math” from Grade 10 onwards to qualify for this stream, which also includes calculus. So calculus based answers are also acceptable as long as they aren’t undergrad level stuff

Comment: https://oeis.org/A007051

Comment: You might be getting into trouble by not terminating your sums but being carefree about where they end with .....  Your ideas are good.  [By keeping  track of where the sum ends, you might be able to get a simple recursion that you could solve in closed form.]

Comment: What do you suggest I should do? This seems like a series within a series within a series. There’s usually a trick to these but with this one I’m not seeing it @Randall

Comment: I recommend looking for a recursion, if you know about that.

Comment: @MartinR That seems very relevant, unfortunately it’s nigh-unreadable likely because the page is quite old. If you know the solution in the link well, would you mind writing it as an answer?

Comment: $S_5 = 3 + 6 + 15  + 42 + 123$ and 

$\frac{S_5}{3} = 3 + (6-1) + (15-1) + (42-1)$ Note the missing $123$ and 

hence $\frac{S_n}{3} = S_{n-1} + n-2 $ which is a correct expression but not useful to the problem at hand. Well you can use generating functions to solve the recurrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally loathe problems like this, because the pattern is not immediately clear; only when the pattern is clear should one implement a sort of "$\cdots$" shorthand. Otherwise it becomes a "read my mind and guess what sequence I had in mind" sort of problem.

Rant aside. Let's look at this equation:
$$\frac{S}{3}=1+2+5+14+41...$$
Making some generous assumptions on the continuation of the pattern, consider the consecutive differences in the terms:
$$\begin{align*}
2-1 &= 1 \\
5-2 &= 3 \\
14-5 &= 9 \\
41 - 14 &= 27 \end{align*}$$

Generally, this suggests to me that the difference in these terms will be a power of $3$, always.

> *This is where my solution gets a bit off the rails; while my instinct is to use this method due to past experience, it is a little clunky since I haven't studied difference equations formally, and it pulls off of a lot of intuitions from ordinary calculus. Not exactly a typical eleventh-grade subject.*

Expressed mathematically, we would use the "backward difference" operator $\Delta$ on the sequence $a_n$ (where $S/3 =  a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n$, i.e. $a_n$ denotes the terms of the sum we desire). The backward difference is defined by
$$
\Delta a_n = a_n - a_{n-1}
$$
so we have
$$
\Delta a_n = 3^n
$$
This backward difference is analogous to the derivative, so if we integrate we can (roughly) undo this -- or, rather, get a rough guess as to what $a_n$ really is, and tweak the result as needed to make it match the pattern we see.

We note
$$
\int 3^n \, \mathrm{d}n = \frac{1}{\ln(3)} \cdot 3^n + C
$$

To me, then, this suggests that $a_n$ takes a form like
$$
a_n = A \cdot 3^n + B
$$
for some constants $A,B$. Try plugging in $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = 2$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
1 &= 3A + B \\
2 &= 9A + B
\end{align*}$$
Solving this system of equations via any method of your preference, we get that
$$
A = \frac 1 6 \qquad B = \frac 1 2
$$
so
$$
a_n = \frac{3^{n-1} + 1}{2}
$$
(Up to the initial index, this matches the [OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A007051) in Martin R.'s comment.)

Therefore, you seek
$$
\frac S 3 = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{3^{k-1} + 1}{2}
$$
This is a fairly straightforward summation to find as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{3^{k-1} + 1}{2}
= \frac 1 2 \sum_{k=1}^n 3^{k-1} + \frac 1 2 \sum_{k=1}^n 1
$$
The first sum is geometric, and the second one is obvious.

Comment: This seems to work, and we have learned calculus so I could likely attempt this in the exam and score some marks on this problem, but is it really not possible through “usual” methods?

Comment: It might be possible with more elementary methods. This is simply the first method that came to mind, though. The majority of the issue lies with determining what $a_n$ is in this scenario since it's not explicitly given to you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the recurrence formula $a_1=3,\thinspace a_{k+1}=3a_k-3$, then your summation is equivalent to :

$$3^1\\
3^2-3\\
3^3-3^2-3\\
3^4-3^3-3^2-3\\
\dots\dots\dots$$

which implies :

$$
\begin{align}a_k&=3^k-(3^1+\cdots+3^{k-1})\\
&=\frac {3^k+3}{2}\end{align}
$$

Thus, we conclude that :

$$
\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k&=\frac {\sum_{k=1}^{n}3^k+3n}{2}\\
&=\frac {3^{n+1}+6n-3}{4}\end{align}
$$

which completes the answer .

Answer (score 1):

Following the idea of your second attempt, we have that

- $a_1=3$
- $a_k=a_{k-1}+3^{k-1}$

therefore the $n$ terms of $S$ given by rows are

- $3$
- $3+3$
- $3+3+9$
- $3+3+9+27$
- $3+3+9+27+81$
- $3+3+9+27+81+243$
- $\ldots$
- $3+3+9+27+81+243+\ldots+3^{n-1}$

that is, summing by columns

$$S=3n+3(n-1)+3^2(n-2)+3^3(n-3)+\ldots+3^{n-1}=$$

$$=3n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}3^k(n-k)=\frac34(3^n+2n-1) \tag 1$$

or, more simply, summing by diagonals

$$S=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(3+\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}3^k\right)=3n+\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{3^i-3}{2}=$$
$$=\frac{3n}2+\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n3^i =\frac{3n}2+\frac{3^n-3}{4}=\boxed{\frac34(3^n+2n-1)}$$

---

Derivation of $(1)$

We have that

$$3n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}3^k(n-k)=3n+ n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}3^k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\;3^k$$

with the geometric series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}3^k=\frac{3^n-3}{2}$$

and

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\;3^k=\frac{n\;3^n}2-\frac 34 (3^n-1)$$

which can be also derived by geometric series using that

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k \implies f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} kx^{k-1}\implies \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} kx^k=xf'(x)$$

Comment: Can you explain how you evaluated that sum at the end? That seems to be the hardest part for me

Comment: @KvochurBell Yes of course I add the derivation.

Answer (score 0):

$$3+6+15+42+\space...\space+a_n$$
$$=(3)+(3+3)+(3+3+9)+(3+3+9+27)+\space...\space+a_n$$
$$=2n+\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^k 3^{l-1}=2n+\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{3^k}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{3n} 2+\frac{3^{n+1}} 4-\frac{3}{4}$$

**Proof of the inside sum**
$$S_k=\sum_{l=0}^k 3^l$$
$$3S_k=\sum_{l=0}^k3^{l+1}=\sum_{l=1}^{k+1}3^l$$
$$S_k-3S_k=-2S_k=\sum_{l=0}^k 3^l-\sum_{l=1}^{k+1}3^l=3^0-3^{k+1}$$
$$S_k=\sum_{l=0}^k 3^l=\frac{3^{k+1}-1}{2}$$